# Как сделать круглые углы у jButton с цветом background'a в java

Tags: java, swing, button, background, border

Всем добрый день. Есть приложение на swing. В приложении есть панель с кнопками. Задача: У ВСЕХ кнопок надо закруглить углы. Желательно чтобы это было сделано через UIManager. Так же, стоит учесть что кнопкам задан фоновый цвет и цвет при зажатой кнопки. пробовал сделать так, но тогда фоновый цвет выходит за углы:

```
button.setBorder(new Border() {
    @Override
    public void paintBorder (Component c, Graphics g,int x, int y, int width, int height){
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, 13, 13);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets (Component c){
        return new Insets(13 + 1, 13 + 1, 13 + 2, 13);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque () {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Я в тупике)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CircleBtn extends  JButton {
    public CircleBtn(String text) {
        super(text);

        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = size.height = Math.max(size.width, size.height);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (getModel().isArmed()) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);//Цвет фона при нажатой кнопке
            setForeground(Color.yellow);//Цвет надписи при нажатой кнопке
        } else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());//Цвет фона
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);//Цвет надписи
        }
        g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1, 13, 13);

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getForeground());
        g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1, 13,13);
    }
}
```

Класс унаследованный от JButton. Переопределил в нем методы отрисовки формы кнопки paintBorder и метод отрисовки внутренних элементов paintComponent.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это действительно помогло!